# Does the decimal expansion of a rational number contain the decimal expansion of an irrational number?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $s \in [0,1] \cap \mathbb{Q}$. Take the decimal expansion of $s$ as $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x_n}{10^n}$ for a sequence $(x_n) \subset \{0,1,...,9\}$ that does not eventually end in a tail of 9's (implying uniqueness).

<strike>**Suppose $(x_n)$ does not also end in a tail of 0's.**</strike> **Suppose $(x_n)$ has finitely many 0's.** Let $P_n$ denote the $n$th prime number. Is $s_p=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x_{P_n}}{10^{P_n}}$ irrational?

It seems the decimal expansion of $s_p$ is supposedly 'random'. If true, it implies that pretty much every rational number "contains" the decimal expansion of an irrational number, which sorta makes sense considering the uncountability of $\mathbb{R}-\mathbb{Q}$. It also makes sense in that you are able to add two irrational numbers to produce a rational number.

I'll do an example. Let $s=\frac{1}{3}=0.\bar{3}$. Then $s_p=0.03303030003030...$, which is clearly irrational.

Edit:
@DanielFischer showed $s=\frac{1}{99}=0.\overline{01}$ is a counterexample, as every odd-indexed digit is 0. Therefore $x_{P_n}=0$ since $P_n$ is odd for $n > 1$, implying $s_p=\frac{1}{100}$.

Comment: $(x_n)$ eventually settles down into a recurring sequence (perhaps you already know this). But I would be surprised if it was known one way or the other whether your sum is always irrational or not.

Comment: Because if the decimal representation has finitely many non-zero digits, then $s_p$ will have finitely many terms.

Comment: @egorovik Ah, true, but I am also assuming $(x_n)$ does not end in a tail of 0's. Therefore $(x_n)$ has an infinite amount of non-zero digits.

Comment: I see. I didn't read that part. Then you can provably show that $s_p$ is transcendental. They will probably be a [Liouville number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville_number), since the sequence of primes has arbitrarily large gaps. But one would need to fiddle with the distribution of those gaps, how frequently they occur.

Comment: Let $s = \frac{1}{99}$. Then $s_p = \frac{1}{100}$. You need a condition ensuring that $x_{p_n} \neq 0$ infinitely often.

Comment: @DanielFischer Correct, which is why I wrote that $(x_n)$ does not end in a tail of 0's. That's sufficient, right?

Comment: No, @SpencerKraisler, it isn't. $\frac{1}{99} = 0.\overline{01}$ doesn't end in a tail of $0$s, but all $x_{2m+1}$ are $0$, and there are only finitely many even primes.

Comment: @DanielFischer Ooh, clever catch. I suppose I should change it to finitely many zeros in $(x_n)$.

Comment: That would be safe, but maybe a little drastic.

Comment: @DanielFischer That's true. Well, I could say that $(x_n)$ cannot eventually become sequence where odd indexed digits are 0.

Comment: @SpencerKraisler Not quite, because that argument could be easily extended to several other cases, whethre the repeating digits have prime length of composite length. IE Take $n$, and in the places that are coprime to $n$, set them to be 0.  Set the rest to be any other value. E.g. $0.\overline{001} \rightarrow 0.001$, $ 0.\overline{0102} \rightarrow 0.01$, etc.

Comment: @CalvinLin That's true. Is there. a way of saying "0's cannot crop up periodically"?

Comment: Another case that fails is $s=\frac 13$.  That makes $x_{P_n}$ always $3$ and the sum is again $\frac 13$.  More generally, if $s$ eventually has the same digits in all the $6k+1$ and $6k+5$ positions, the sum will be rational.  You need to think carefully about the question.

Comment: @RossMillikan that's not true. $s_p = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x_{P_n}}{10^{P_n}}$, not $s_p = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x_{P_n}}{10^{n}}$. Therefore $s \not = s_p$

Comment: But it sill make $s_p$ rational because eventually all the $x_{P_n}$ will be the same, which is what I said.

Comment: @RossMillikan Wouldn't $s_p=0.03303030003030...$, which is a non-periodic decimal expansion?

Comment: @RossMillikan No, as long as infinitely many $x_{p_n}$ are nonzero, $s_p$ is irrational. Its decimal expansion contains arbitrarily long strings of $0$, so the only possibility of $s_p$ being rational is it having a finite expansion.

Comment: I missed that the denominator in $s_p$ was $10^{P_n}$, not $10^n$

Comment: @DanielFischer, sorry, I unintentionally duplicated your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Unless the $x_{p_n}$s are all eventually $0$, the maximum number of consecutive $0$s between nonzero terms in $0.0x_2x_30x_50x_7000x_{11}0x_{13}\ldots$ grows without limit, since the maximum number of consecutive composite numbers grows without limit (e.g., $n!+2,n!+3,n!+4,\ldots,n!+n$), so no number of the OP's given form, with the assumption that $x_n=0$ for only finitely many $n$, can be rational.

Comment: Oh, I just saw Daniel Fischer's comment below the OP. This answer duplicates that comment.